How do I access pixel data using rpicam-apps?
I have searched around for this alot, but found nothing (maybe my searching is thwarted). I can edit and use the post-processing-files in rpicam-apps, but I want to find the brightest pixel and just output its coordinates. This is for running rpicam-vid or rpicam-raw.

Are you trying to use one of the applications that comes with rpicam-apps, or are you looking for advice using libcamera, which those apps are built on top of?
